# ngUpgrade in production app/website?

Tags: angularjs, ng-upgrade

We have an app/website using Angular 1.5. It'll take time to convert everything to Angular 2 and it isn't a priority as what we have currently work.

I was thinking it could be interesting for new components/directive/services to write them in Angular 2, to avoid having to eventually convert them later on, as well as to start learning the new syntax.

But is it really a good idea to **ship** something containing Angular 1.5 and 2 with ngUpgrade? The memory footprint should end up being bigger, but are there other drawbacks?

The following article http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html by Pascal Precht mentions: `Keep in mind that the goal of this [upgrade] phase is to stay in it as little as possible, since running both frameworks on the same website is surely not ideal.` but that doesn't tell us much.

Does anyone have feedbacks with a "real" (ie not tiny or proof of concept) partial update using ngUpgrade?

Comment: Curious to know what you chose to do and how it's worked out?

Comment: @eflat: we actually stayed on Angular 1 for that app as no new development was forseen. It seemed like too much work to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

We have a large commercial product (banking web-application) and we use a hybrid application on production.

We migrate services and components from AngularJS 1.5 to Angular 6, and it will take at least a half year.

A few tips:

1. To avoid all issues with `$digest` and performance I recommend using [DowngradeModule](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeModule) - it bootstraps AngularJS outside of the Angular zone and keeps the two change detection systems separate.
   The first hybrid app used [UpgradeModule](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeModule) and we had a lot of problems, - this approach is not for large applications.
2. Use similar code before `bootstrapModule(AppModule)`

> ```
> import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
>
> if (IS_PRODUCTION) {
>    enableProdMode();
> }
> ```

If you have any questions - you are welcome.